# Add new tags in custom binding

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding, bootstrap-tokenfield

I am using knockout with [bootstrap-tokenfield](https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield) and [typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) to show tags. Previously I needed a way to show my tags in a nice way and therefore I created a custom binding. It worked really nice when the list of tags was not changing and only selected tags were changing.

So a really simplified example [looks like this](http://jsfiddle.net/sg9VA/6/). As you see, you can type various tags (`tag1`, `tag2`, ..., `tag5`) and observable is changing. So my custom binding works in this case.

Here it is:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tags = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var initializeTags = function(listOfTags, inputID, max){
            var tags = new Bloodhound({
                local: listOfTags,
                datumTokenizer: function(d) {return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);},
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
            });
            tags.initialize();
            inputID.tokenfield({
                limit : max,
                typeahead: {source: tags.ttAdapter()}
            }).on('tokenfield:preparetoken', function (e) {
                var str = e.token.value,
                    flag = false,
                    i, l;
                for(i = 0, l = listOfTags.length; i < l; i++){
                    if (listOfTags[i]['value'] === str){
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!flag){
                    e.token = false;
                }
            });
        }

        var options = allBindings().tagsOptions,
            currentTagsList = Helper.tags1List,
            currentTagsInverted = Helper.tags1Inverted;

        initializeTags(currentTagsList, $(element), 4);

        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var tags = $(element).tokenfield('getTokens'),
                tagsID = [],
                observable = valueAccessor(), i, l, tagID;

            for (i = 0, l = tags.length, tagID; i < l; i++){
                tagID = currentTagsInverted[tags[i].value];

                if (typeof tagID !== 'undefined'){
                    tagsID.push(parseInt(tagID));
                }
            }

            observable( tagsID );
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var arr     = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            options = allBindings().tagsOptions,
            currentTags = Helper.tags1, tagsName = [], i, l, tagName;

        if ( !(arr instanceof Array) ){
            arr = [];
        }

        for (i = 0, l = arr.length, tagName; i < l; i++){
            tagName = currentTags[arr[i]];
            if (typeof tagName !== 'undefined'){
                tagsName.push(tagName);
            }

        }
        $(element).tokenfield('setTokens', tagsName);
    }
};
```

But the problem is that I need to add additional tag: `tag6` and if I simply do

```
Helper.getAllTags({
    "1":{"value":"tag1"}, ..., "6":{"value":"tag6"}
})
```

it will not work (which is not a surprise to me, I know why it does not work). What it the proper way of doing this.

**P.S.**

- If you think that my binding is terrible, I agree with you and would be happy to hear how to improve it.
- If you need clarification about how binding work, I will be happy to provide it.
- Idea of having `tags1, tags1List, tags1Inverted` is to be able to quickly find appropriate tag either by id or by name (I have like 500 of them).
- if you want to change many things you are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Updated answer, 'correct' pattern

I've created a KnockoutJS binding for bootstrap-tokenfield.

https://github.com/mryellow/knockoutjs-tokenfield

First up lets look at `update`s coming in from the `valueAccessor()`.

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var observable = valueAccessor() || { };
    var peeked = ko.unwrap(observable.peek());

    ko.tokenfield[element.id].handlerEnabled = false;

    $(element).tokenfield('setTokens',peeked);

    ko.tokenfield[element.id].handlerEnabled = true;
}
```

Here we create tokens for any incoming data from the model. All the tokens, as `valueAccessor()` gives us the complete object. This however will trigger `tokenfield:createdtoken` which is on the `init` side of our binding. So to avoid re-saving these tokens to the model we set a variable `handlerEnabled` to control the events flow.

Now for any user interaction, HTML `value` attributes, or model changes this event will be triggered:

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'tokenfield:createdtoken', function (e) {
    // Detect private token created.
    if (e.attrs[ko.tokenfield[element.id].bindings['KeyDisplay']].indexOf("_") === 0) {
        console.log('tt-private');
        $(e.relatedTarget).addClass('tt-private');
    }

    // Allow `update` to temporarily disable pushing back when this event fires.
    if (ko.tokenfield[element.id].handlerEnabled == true) observable.push(e.attrs);

});
```

Note the `handlerEnabled` global to block re-adding to the `valueAccessor()`.

When removing tokens the extra meta-data that came from our AJAX autocomplete is missing from tokenfield ([patched](https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield/commit/e9e0c4cce3458b46e38f7af51871e945cf99d53f)). Thus we must look it up based on the attributes that do exist:

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'tokenfield:removedtoken', function (e) {
    var peeked = observable.peek();
    var item;
    // Find item using tokenfield default values, other values are not in tokenfield meta-data.
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(peeked, function(x) {
        if (ko.unwrap(x.label) === e.attrs.label && ko.unwrap(x.value) === e.attrs.value) item = x;
    });

    observable.remove(item); // Validation of `item` likely needed
});
```

So that about covers the internals of the binder. Now we're saving everything directly into the bound model as KnockoutJS would expect, without the duplication of data or sync issues. Lets get that CSV field back, using a `observableArray.fn` which returns a computed is nice and reusable.

Usage: `self.tags_csv = self.tags.computeCsv();`.

```
ko.observableArray['fn'].computeCsv = function() {
    console.log('observableArray.computeCsv');
    var self = this;        

    return ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            console.log('computed.read');

            var csv = '';
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(ko.unwrap(self), function(item) {
                console.log('item:'+JSON.stringify(item));
                if (csv != '') csv += ',';
                // Our ID from AJAX response.
                if (item.id !== undefined) {
                    csv += item.id;
                // Tokenfield's ID form `value` attrs.
                } else if (item.value !== undefined) {
                    csv += item.value;
                // The label, no ID available.
                } else {
                    csv += item.label;
                }                   
            });

            return csv;
        },
        write: function (value) {
            console.log('computed.write');

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(value.split(','), function(item) {
                self.push({
                    label: item,
                    value: item
                });
            });

        }
    });
};
```

Now we have an array of objects and a CSV representation in our model, ready to be mapped or manipulated before sending to server.

```
"tags": [
    {
        "label": "tag1",
        "value": "tag1"
    },
    {
        "id": "id from AJAX",
        "field": "field from AJAX",
        "label": "tag2",
        "value": "tag2"
    }
],
"tags_csv": "tag1,id from AJAX"
```

Comment: Seems tokenfield does actually store the extra meta-data on the token, id etc.

Answer (score 0):

## This answer is backwards

Please refer to the other version.

---

Adding the `addItem()`/`removeItem()` to the model directly helps keep things a little more managable. Below is my model which contains the items associated with each field.

```
var tokenFieldModel = function tokenFieldModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.items = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.addItem = function(attrs) {
        console.log('addItem');
        self.items.push(new tokenItemModel(attrs));
    };

    this.removeItem = function(attrs) {
        console.log('removeItem');
        var item;
        if (attrs.id != null) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.items(), function(x) {
                if(x.id === attrs.id && ko.unwrap(x.value) == attrs.value) item = x;
            });
        } else {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.items(), function(x) {
                // TODO: Use allBindingsAccessor().tokenFieldDisplay
                if(ko.unwrap(x.value) === attrs.value) item = x;
            });
        }
        //console.log(ko.unwrap(this.items()));
        self.items.remove(item);
    };
};
```

The `removeItem()` looks messy having to loop through things but is a bit particular to my situation, I want to add tokens that haven't been matched against the autocomplete and don't have `id` or any other object keys. They'll only have the text/label that created the token.

I can then sent this to the server looking something like:

```
field_id = "id:111, id:222, a new tag, id:333, another new tag"
```

or

```
field_id = [
    {
        id: 111,
        value: 'tag1',
        label: 'tag1'
    },
    {
        id: 222,
        value: 'tag2',
        label: 'tag2'
    },
    {
        value: 'a new tag'
    },
]
```

This then allows me to create tokens that aren't prefixed. I'm using Couchbase NoSQL so this fits right in with how data/documents are stored.

Thus `removeItem()` has to search through the array attempting to match either an `id` or falling back only looking for the `value`. This part could be improved to accept a binding variable from `allBindingsAccessor()` to control which field is matched.

Now inside the binder's `init` we can define eventHandlers that will respond to tokenfield.

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'tokenfield:removedtoken', function (e) {
    console.log('tokenfield:removedtoken');
    console.log(e);

    tokenBaseModel.fields[element.id].removeItem(e.attrs);
});
```

Note that I have each tokenfield on the page inside an array `tokenBaseModel.fields()` indexed by their `elementId` (not an `obserableArray()`, just a normal array to store separate items lists for each tokenfield on the page).

```
var tokenBaseModel = {
    fields: []
};
```

Then in the binders `update` section we can pass the value in our tokenfield back to other models as defined in the `data-bind` attribute itself.

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
    console.log('update');
    var observable = valueAccessor() || {};

    // Does validation on allBindingsAccessor and sets defaults.
    var bindings = new tokenFieldUtils().processBindings(allBindingsAccessor);

    // An `fn` util function extending both `observableArray` and `observable` to accept whichever datatype they're expecting and sort it out.
    observable.refreshAll(ko.unwrap(tokenBaseModel.fields[element.id].items),bindings['Delimiter'],bindings['FieldKey']);

}
```

Then finally my `refreshAll()` (actually `valueAccessor()().refreshAll()`) function does the heavy-lifting of passing the data back to the `valueAccessor()`.

```
 ko.observableArray['fn'].refreshAll = function(valuesToPush, delimiter, key) {
    var underlyingArray = this();
    this.valueWillMutate();
    this.removeAll();
    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(underlyingArray, valuesToPush);
    this.valueHasMutated();
    return this;
};

ko.observable['fn'].refreshAll() = function(valuesToPush, delimiter, key) {
    this.valueWillMutate();
    var csv = '';
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(valuesToPush, function(item) {
        if (csv != '') csv += delimiter;
        if (item[key] === undefined) {
            csv += item['value'];
        } else {
            csv += item[key];
        }
    });
    this(csv);
    this.valueHasMutated();
    return this;
};
```

Defining the binding as `data-bind="tokenfield: fooModel.bar"` means `valueAccessor()` will be evaluated to the external field `fooModel.bar` which is outside the scope of my tokenfield models.
(`valueAccessor()` is actual a function to get/set, not a link directly to the value).

Then finally hitting `valueHasMutated()` triggers the changes to update in other elements where `fooModel.bar` is bound.

Comment: Woohoo! Score! I've joined those who can comment and make fools of themselves. ;-) Thanx.

Comment: Note the "update" using the items array instead of valueAccessor means it can't accept values from outside to create new tokens, complete with id and other fields. It can however create tokens from a value attribute as tokenfield fires off create token events for these. Working on a two-way solution, might have to only support arrays and handle building CSVs on the other end so all the keys are always stored.

Comment: Ok so that was an interesting approach but not 'correct' for dealing with KnockoutJS. Taking advantage of incoming updates from the parent model is possible, starting by using `peek` to view the contents without unintentionally subscribing to our `items` array. Can also overwrite `notifySubscribers`. However this quickly results in a race condition where you are chasing around dirty flags and needing to sync the internal models with external. Instead of all this marshalling of changes and constantly reconstructing the CSV, using external models and computered observable is better pattern.

Comment: k sorted, please accept new answer. Original left for history, has some techniques in it.